# JDBC Deployment Error - NoClassDefFound

Tags: java, linux, jdbc, netbeans, oracle12c

I've been working with a Java program which performs several queries against an Oracle database. I'm currently using the jdbc thin client (ojdbc7.jar) for this. For an IDE I'm using NetBeans, and debugging  or running the JAR on my PC I've faced no Errors. Running this JAR on a Linux environment for production however, the following error is reported:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver
    [...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

The code I'm using to get the connection is:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
Connection conn = null;
Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
connectionProps.put("user", DBUsername);
connectionProps.put("password", DBPassword);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBCConnection, DBUsername, DBPassword);
```

With DBUsername/Password and JDBCConnection all being locally stored. Adding additional print statements shows the failing line is:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
```

I currently have  ojdbc7.jar included under Libraries in my project. Checking the project properties under Build > Packaging, "Copy Dependent Libraries" is checked. My expectation at this point is the library should be included in my jar file.

I have also tested:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
```

Similarly, I've tried using only Class.forName(), and using both.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

Reading other questions, I understand this could be an issue with my classpath. In the Linux environment I'm trying to run this in, I set the classpath to the exact location of the ocjdb7.jar without luck:

```
export CLASSPATH=/<Directory Location>/ocjdb7.jar
```

I've tried multiple configurations of this, for example the Linux environment in question already had a classpath including ocjdb6.jar, so I recompiled with this version, set the classpath, and tested. Same error message reported. Have I missed a necessary setup to include this driver? Testing on a coworkers Windows 7 desktop, the same error occurred which seems to indicate this is still a setup issue.

Comment: Thanks ujulu, should there have been a link in your comment?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I linked to the document. [Here](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html) is the document I wanted to link to.

Comment: Appreciate it! I'll read through.

Comment: Thanks ujulu! I realized I was making a silly mistake. Specifically from your link:
"If you have specified any libraries for the project (in addition to the JDK), a lib folder is created in the dist folder. The libraries are copied into dist/lib."
I had to copy the lib folder to the target as well. After doing so, the JAR ran without issues. If you'd like to turn that into an answer, I'll accept yours over mine.

Comment: Glad it helped you. If you add the link to your answer, it might help others with similar problems to better understand the problem and solve it. I just upvote your answer so that others might find it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple - Netbeans includes any referenced libraries in a lib folder under the dist folder it compiles the JAR files to. I had been copying only the compiled JAR, but not the associated lib folder. After copying the lib folder, the process ran without exceptions.

Netbeans documentation covers how this functions, which states:
https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html

> If you have specified any libraries for the project (in addition to the JDK), a lib folder is created in the dist folder. The libraries are copied into dist/lib.

Answer (score 0):

The *ocjdb7.jar* should be packaged into your executable JAR. I suggest you try to make a maven project out of it (NetBeans should have a convenient wizard for that) and reference it as a dependency. 
You can also check, if the required *ocjdb7.jar* was packaged into your JAR when you extract it (a JAR is just an archive file).

Comment: Do you have any links I could follow on how I should properly package this into my JAR? I'll look into a Maven project, I'm unfamiliar.